# Java Servlet How to filter pages by User Role

Tags: java, servlets

I'm coding a security web app. And I have a problem. For example , there is a pages called " Manager (JSP) " . I only want admins to see this page.

When user login the website , session create.

```
if(dao.check(uname, pass)) {
        UserAccount user = new UserAccount();
        user.setUsername(uname);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", uname);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    }
```

Heres the UserAccount Class :

```
public class UserAccount {
private String username;
private String password;
private List<String> roles;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public List<String> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

}

And i have a Filter class which implements Filter. How program get understand who is admin or not and let to see manager page?

Comment: You should first question: how the detect the user? You need some sort of login page and either a session cookie of transfer the session ID as a get/post parameter in every HTTP request. When you have the session ID, you can load the related session object from some container (or DB) and the session can tell which role the user has. Of yourse you need some database to link users with roles.

Comment: you can check my suggestion

Comment: What is your application server (i.e. Tomcat, Wildfly, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean attribute in your UserAccount class , this attribute will hold a value of `true` if the use is an admin , and false if he is not

```
public class UserAccount {
private String username;
private String password;
private List<String> roles;
private boolean is_admin;
...}
```

The redirection to manager page will see first if the current user is admin or not , so he will be denied if he's not an admin

---

**NB : i see that you are using a List of roles , so maybe you're using a Role-Based access control ( like *RBAC* or *RABAC* )**

In that case maybe you're giving admin permissions through his roles , so here the Filter method will see the user's roles list and check if it contains the role of admin , and if yes it will redirect into the manager page